# Stacked barplot with different colors for each bar in base R

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart, legend, stacked

I am trying to create a figure with subplots with stacked barplots. I would like each bar to have a different color gradually changing across categories in the x-axis. I also want the stacked part of each bar to be slightly lighter than the bottom part of the bar. It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818271/stacked-barplot-with-colour-gradients-for-each-bar) but I want the gradient in color across bars (and not within). It is also similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180673/r-barplot-different-color-for-certain-bars) in that the bottom part is darker than the stacked part of the bar but I want to see if there is a way to do that in base R without using ggplot.

Finally, I want to put a common legend in the middle right of the entire plot but I cannot get it to move from the bottomright area. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389967/common-legend-for-multiple-plots-in-r?) but it is not working.

Here are my data and codes.

```
color <- c('W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 
'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 
'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl', 'W', 'Y', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'Br', 'Gr', 'Bl')
mass <- c(10, 14, 20, 15, 16, 13, 11, 15, 10, 14, 23, 18, 12, 22, 20, 13, 14, 17, 20, 22, 24, 17, 23, 18, 14, 15, 16, 19, 17, 15, 15, 21, 22, 18,
15, 21, 19, 23, 14, 18, 15, 23, 10, 16, 22, 10, 20, 18, 15, 12, 16, 13, 13, 15, 10, 14, 23, 18, 18, 22, 20, 13, 24, 19, 18, 24, 20, 22, 17, 19, 24, 21)
fir.mass <- c(3, 1, 4, 10, 8, 10, 3, 5, 2, 8, 7, 4, 7, 4, 10, 12, 8, 13, 16, 15, 17, 10, 18, 16, 7, 12, 13, 10, 9, 10, 11, 9, 10, 15, 14, 18, 15, 
17, 7, 17, 11, 20, 5, 6, 11, 7, 13, 12, 14, 10, 8, 10, 7, 11, 5, 6, 9, 3, 17, 4, 10, 13, 18, 13, 16, 16, 15, 17, 11, 15, 20, 15)
name <- c('K3', 'K3', 'K3', 'K3', 'K3', 'K3', 'K3', 'K3', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2', 'B2',
'D3', 'D3', 'D3', 'D3', 'D3', 'D3', 'D3', 'D3', 'K1', 'K1', 'K1', 'K1', 'K1', 'K1', 'K1', 'K1', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 'D2', 
'B3', 'B3', 'B3', 'B3', 'B3', 'B3', 'B3', 'B3', 'K2', 'K2', 'K2', 'K2', 'K2', 'K2', 'K2', 'K2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1')

pet.data <- data.frame(color, name, mass, fir.mass)

# Specify which individual belongs to which pet
kitty <- c('K1', 'K2', 'K3')
bunny <- c('B1', 'B2', 'B3')
doggy <- c('D1', 'D2', 'D3')

# Create gradually changing colors
blackcolors <- colorRampPalette(c('white', 'black'))
# I want the stacked part to be lighter in color than the bottom part
graycolors <- colorRampPalette(c('white', 'black'))

par(mfrow = c(3, 3), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1), oma = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 6), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))
for (i in 1: nlevels(pet.data$name)) {
pet.type <- ifelse(levels(pet.data$name)[i] %in% kitty, 'kitty', ifelse(levels(pet.data$name)[i] %in% bunny, 'bunny', 'doggy'))
pet.name <- levels(pet.data$name)[i]
barplot(rbind(pet.data$mass[pet.data$name == levels(pet.data$name)[i]], pet.data$fir.mass[pet.data$name == levels(pet.data$name)[i]]),
    main = substitute(paste('Size of  ', bold('lovely '), pet.type, ' (', pet.name, ')'),
    env = list(pet.type = pet.type, pet.name = pet.name)),
    xlab = 'Fir color', ylab = 'Mass', las = 1,
    names = c('White', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Pink', 'Red', 'Brown', 'Gray', 'Black'), col = c(blackcolors(8), graycolors(8)))
abline(h = 0)
}

# I want to add a legend in the middle right but it is not working
legend(x = 'right', y = 'middle', inset = c(-0.1, 0), legend = c('Body', 'Fir'), fill = c(blackcolors(8), graycolors(8)), bty = 'n', cex = 1.2, xpd = TRUE)
```

This is what I get.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Could somebody please help fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first define the colors:

```
COLS = colorRampPalette(c('grey90', 'grey10'))(24)
graycolors <- COLS[seq(1,24,by=3)]
blackcolors <- COLS[seq(3,24,by=3)]
```

I would suggest using layout, since you have 9 plots, you place the order of the plots in a 3x3 matrix, and the last column will be all legend.

```
# don't set mfrow here
par(mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1), oma = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 6), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))
LAY = cbind(matrix(1:9,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE),rep(10,3))
```

You specify the relative widths of the column so the legend column will be "squashed" horizontally:

```
layout(LAY, widths=c(4,4,4,1))
```

Then use your same plot with a internal for loop (from [koekenbakker's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781685/different-colors-for-each-bar-in-stacked-bar-graph-base-graphics)) to add the colors:

```
for (i in 1: nlevels(pet.data$name)) {    
pet.type <- ifelse(levels(pet.data$name)[i] %in% kitty, 'kitty', ifelse(levels(pet.data$name)[i] %in% bunny, 'bunny', 'doggy'))
pet.name <- levels(pet.data$name)[i]
mat = rbind(pet.data$mass[pet.data$name == levels(pet.data$name)[i]], 
pet.data$fir.mass[pet.data$name == levels(pet.data$name)[i]])

barplot(mat,
main = substitute(paste('Size of  ', bold('lovely '), pet.type, ' (', pet.name, ')'),
env = list(pet.type = pet.type, pet.name = pet.name)),
xlab = 'Fir color', ylab = 'Mass', las = 1,
names = c('White', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Pink', 'Red', 'Brown', 'Gray', 'Black'), col = "white")
for (i in 1:ncol(mat)){
    xx = mat
    xx[,-i] = NA
    colnames(xx)[-i] = NA
    barplot(xx,col=c(graycolors[i],blackcolors[i]), add=T, axes=F) 
}
}
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
legend(x="center", legend = c('Body', 'Fir'),
fill = c(graycolors[1],blackcolors[1]), bty = 'n', cex = 1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This resolves the issue of having a common legend at the center-right of ally my subplots. Do you know how I could change bar colors as in the Wietze314's solution using base R?

Comment: Yeah you can.. see above, i will try to wrap it around in a function to make it less messy. But that's how it will go.. A bit complicated? Lol

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you! Fir mass is lighter than body mass so I figure the legend is opposite (the lighter color is supposed to be body and the darker color is supposed to be fir in your script)?

Comment: Hey @owl, yeah thanks for pointing it out. I flipped the legend. And it doesn't look so obvious in the plot, so might want to choose other contrast along graycolors and blackcolors for the legend.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a head start, but is done with `ggplot`.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggplot2)

pet.data %>%
  gather(key,value,-color,-name) %>%
  mutate(fillcolor = as.numeric(color) + if_else(key == 'mass',.5,0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = value, fill = fillcolor, color = key)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap(.~name) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","black")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey",high = "#111111") +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill = FALSE,
         color = guide_legend(title = "", override.aes = list(fill = c('#555555','grey'))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I would like something like this in base R.

Comment: Why would you want to stick to base R? As you can see, with `ggplot` the code can stay quite clean. I edited the code to provide a black/white solution.

Comment: Thank you for your codes in ggplot. Your codes do make it obvious how you can create a similar graph with fewer codes compared to base R! I am still learning how to use ggplot so that is one reason I stick with base R but for my purpose, I also want very simple figures so a lot of frames and lines (which makes graphs look fancier) that come by default in ggplot (I assume?) makes base R better but would that be pretty simple to change in ggplot?

Comment: Sure there are some default themes you can use like I used `theme_bw()`. And apart from that, everything is custamizable with `theme()`